# Upload rate of server and download rate of client, which will matter?

Tags: networking

I am learning about P2P networks, I am confused about the **Upload rate of server** and **download rate of client**. So if a client is downloading files from server, which rate will matter?

Answer (score 1):

The smallest of the available upload rate of the server and the available download rate of the client will set the upper limit for the rate of a given transfer.

Comment: what do you mean by `transfer`? For example if I have a server with upload rate 200mbs, and a client download rate 100bps, so where the file will be when the server finish upload and the client is still downloading?

Comment: E.g. the protocol TCP will adapt the rate so that the server isn't sending faster than the client can receive. Some data will reside in buffers on the server and client and some will be in transfer.